# Improve setting values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add some columns for group features(std, mean...), the code below works but the dataset is really big and the performance is bad. Is there any good idea to improve the code? Thanks

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,1], [1,2,2], [1,3,3], [1,3,4],[2,8,9], [2,11,11]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df['mean'] = 0

df2 = df.groupby('A')
for a, group in df2:
    mean = group['C'].mean()
    df.loc[df['A'] == a, 'mean'] = mean

df
'''
     A   B   C  mean
0   1   2   1   2.5
1   1   2   2   2.5
2   1   3   3   2.5
3   1   3   4   2.5
4   2   8   9   10.0
5   2   11  11  10.0
'''
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pandas' [**`groupby.transform`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation)  does the job of broadcasting aggregate statistics across the original index.  This makes it perfect for your purposes and should be considered the idiomatic way to perform this task.

pipelined solution that produces a copy of `df` with new column

```
df.assign(Mean=df.groupby('A').C.transform('mean'))

   A   B   C  Mean
0  1   2   1   2.5
1  1   2   2   2.5
2  1   3   3   2.5
3  1   3   4   2.5
4  2   8   9  10.0
5  2  11  11  10.0
```

In place assignment

```
df['Mean'] = df.groupby('A').C.transform('mean')
df

   A   B   C  Mean
0  1   2   1   2.5
1  1   2   2   2.5
2  1   3   3   2.5
3  1   3   4   2.5
4  2   8   9  10.0
5  2  11  11  10.0
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `pd.factorize` and `np.bincount`

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df.A.values)
totals = np.bincount(f, df.C.values)
counts = np.bincount(f)
df.assign(Mean=(totals / counts)[f])

   A   B   C  Mean
0  1   2   1   2.5
1  1   2   2   2.5
2  1   3   3   2.5
3  1   3   4   2.5
4  2   8   9  10.0
5  2  11  11  10.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way:

```
s = df.groupby('A')['C'].mean()

df['mean'] = df['A'].map(s)

#    A   B   C  mean
# 0  1   2   1   2.5
# 1  1   2   2   2.5
# 2  1   3   3   2.5
# 3  1   3   4   2.5
# 4  2   8   9  10.0
# 5  2  11  11  10.0
```

**Explanation**

- First, `groupby` 'A' and calculate `mean` of 'C'. This creates a series with index unique entries in 'A' and values as required.
- Second, `map` this series onto your dataframe. This is possible because `pd.Series.map` can take a series as an input.

Comment: Also, this is of similar theme to your approach `df.join(df.groupby('A').C.mean().rename('Mean'), on='A')`

Answer (score 2):

You can call mean with index

```
df.assign(mean=df.A.map(df.set_index('A').C.mean(level=0)))
Out[28]: 
   A   B   C  mean
0  1   2   1   2.5
1  1   2   2   2.5
2  1   3   3   2.5
3  1   3   4   2.5
4  2   8   9  10.0
5  2  11  11  10.0
```

Or using get

```
df['mean']=df.set_index('A').C.mean(level=0).get(df.A).values
df
Out[35]: 
   A   B   C  mean
0  1   2   1   2.5
1  1   2   2   2.5
2  1   3   3   2.5
3  1   3   4   2.5
4  2   8   9  10.0
5  2  11  11  10.0
```